# Why does ComplexListPlot labeling function require an Evaluate?

Tags: plotting, complex, options

Start with the list of the cube-roots of unity:

```
cubeRoots = ComplexExpand[Exp[(2 \[Pi] Range[0, 2] I)/3]]
```

I want to use `ComplexListPlot` to plot these three points and label each of them with its value.

Noting the the first example in the documentation for the "LabelingFunction" option to `ComplexListPlot`, namely...

```
ComplexListPlot[{1, E^((2 I \[Pi])/7), E^((4 I \[Pi])/7), E^((
   6 I \[Pi])/7), E^((8 I \[Pi])/7), E^((10 I \[Pi])/7), E^((
   12 I \[Pi])/7)} -> {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}]
```

...I tried the following;

```
ComplexListPlot[cubeRoots -> cubeRoots,
  PlotStyle -> Directive[Red, PointSize[Large]],
  Ticks -> None, PlotRange -> 1.5,BaseStyle -> {11},
  ImageSize -> Scaled[0.5]]
```

That fails, with error: "ComplexListPlot called with 0 arguments; 1 argument is expected."

Wrapping the first instance of `cubeRoots` with `Evaluate` works, however:

```
ComplexListPlot[Evaluate[cubeRoots] -> cubeRoots,
 PlotStyle -> Directive[Red, PointSize[Large]],
 Ticks -> None, PlotRange -> 1.5, BaseStyle -> {11},
 ImageSize -> Scaled[0.5]]
```

[image: Cube roots of unity plot]

**Question:** Why is the `Evaluate` needed to wrap around the left-hand side of the Rule that constitutes, in effect, the argument to `ComplexListPlot`?

Comment: What should "cubeRoots -> cubeRoots" mean? It is wrong syntax. Use simply: ComplexListPlot[cubeRoots, ...

Comment: @DanielHuber: No, that doesn't create the callout labels. Please see the docs for option `LabelingFunction` for `ComplexListPlot`.